# Set default value if null in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am looping my results in twig view..

```
{% for item in items %}
    <li> {{ item.userId.firstName }} {{ item.userId.lastName }} </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

I want to set default value 'User unknown' if the user id in database **is NULL** .

Like: `{% if item.userId is null %}` --> than set default value

Note: I am aware of using if else here but as I have this *fistName - lastName* in numerous palace, I wanted to avoid using ***if else*** in every part. I wanted to set that default value everywhere in case userId is null without repeating the code in every place.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Move the logic from the view to the `Item` model/etntity. eg: `Item::getUserFullName()` Please provide the Item model/entity code so we can give a suggestion. Then instead of `i{{ tem.userId.firstname }} {{ item.userId.lastName }}` you would call `{{ item.userFullName }}` across all your views, controllers and models/services/entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

You can set a variable by using:

```
{% set name = item.userId is null ? 'User unknown' : item.userId.firstName ~ ' ' ~ item.userId.lastName %}
```

If by setting you mean outputting 'User unknown', a simple if else statement would do the trick

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.userId is null %}
        <li>User unknown</li>
    {% else %}
        <li> {{ item.userId.firstName }} {{ item.userId.lastName }} </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Maybe I was not clear earlier but I have this fistName - lastName in numerous palaces and I wanted to avoid using if else in every part. I wanted to set that default value everywhere in case userId is null without repeating the code in every place. @ImAtWar

Comment: Thank you. Error: " A non-numeric value encountered" :/ @ImAtWar

Comment: + is incorrect on concatination strings ... use ~ `{% set name = item.userId is null ? 'User unknown' : item.userId.firstName ~ ' ' ~ item.userId.lastName %}`

Comment: Thanks, was just testing in twigg fiddle when you commented :P

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to set defaults in the code that is rendering the output, where `items` is being sent to Twig. `array_merge` is often used for this - `$item = array_merge($defaultItem, $item);`. Here, $item overrides the value set in defaults.

Within the templates, you can also use the null-coalescing operator `??` on individual fields: `{{ item.userId.firstName ?? 'unknown firstName' }}`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but Twig seems to have a filter for default values:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html